# Existential variables in dependent type theory

Tags: type-theory, reference-request

For the kernel of a proof assistant free variables/universal quantification may be sufficient. In higher level languages such as Coq's tactic language indeterminate variables (not sure of the wording here)/existential variables may be useful.

Also personally I'm interested in languages lacking the full power of dependent product/functions so good use of dependent sum/products is really important.

How do you implement indeterminate/existential variables in type theory?

Comment: Do hole/meta variables suit your need?

Comment: Generally they are implemented as metavariables – a concept that is swept under the rug, done badly by mixing object and meta levels, and generally not paid due attention. (If we behaved like this in algebra, we wouldn't teach the fact that polynomials form a ring.)

Comment: @Guest0x0 I think holes/metavariables might work ? I was partially inspired after reading https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~plragde/flane/LACI/Interaction_In_Predicate_Logic.html#%28part._.A_calculus_of_holes%29 to ask this question anyhow. I just don't know enough about holes to know if they are the right construct here.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee Holes/Meta variables behave like existential variables because they can be instantiated exactly once, substituted to exactly one type. However, this process is controlled by the type checker not the user, also you usually cannot quantify over meta variables directly.

Comment: @Guest0x0 so there's not a sort of thing where there's a rule to convert use of metavariables to dependent sum types (and vice-versa?)

Comment: @MolossusSpondee I think no. Actually I think meta variables should not be considered part of the object language, otherwise you just account for type checking and elaboration in metatheory

Comment: @Guest0x0 I mean that would be kind of the point of handling metavariables/holes explicitly to make type checking and elaboration more explicit wouldn't it?

Comment: @MolossusSpondee well, the most common use case of meta variables is to let the type checker fill in something implicitly. If you prefer something explicitly, why not use a Sigma directly? Perhaps something like “let x = _ in (x, ...)”?